# Create object from another one using filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects using an array of objects.
My first array is like that : [image]

And I want to create an object list with only an id, a name and a task.
This is what i do actually, but it doesn't work :

```
var lists = data.filter(l => {
            return new ListModel(l.listId, l.listName, 'todo');
});
```

The ListModel object is :

```
class ListModel {
    constructor(id, name, tasks) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    setId(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    setName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    setTask(task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full `data` object please - even a link to an offsite resource (JSFiddle, Codepen) would be preferable to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` function is more-so utilized for returning an array based upon some search criteria, similar to a WHERE clause. What you want is to utilize is the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function using something like this:

```
var lists = data.map(l => {
    return new ListModel(l.listId, l.listName, 'todo');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .map instead of .filter:

```
var lists = data.map(l => {
            return new ListModel(l.listId, l.listName, 'todo');
});
```

filter is for filtering elements, and the return value is taken as a boolean value for this. So in your case all elements will be validated because a new object is allways a truthy value, and you'll get a equal array.

Edit your question with the original array in text format and I'll create a working example for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `map()` function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Something like this:

```
const newData = data.map( item => {
  return {
    item.listId,
    item.listName,
    'todo',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map instead of filter.

Filter creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function/expression.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which removes non-matching elements from the current array. What you *want* to do, as far as I can tell, is use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array based upon the `ListModel` object. Here's how you'd do it:

```
var lists = data.map(l => new ListModel(l.listId, l.listName, "todo"));
```